# Logical Inverse of a Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, func, linq-expressions

I have some fairly complex Entity Framework queries throughout my codebase and I decided to centralize the logic into the models.  Basically, picture a bunch of controllers with large queries and lots of repeated code in their expression trees.  So I took out parts of those expression trees and moved them to the models, allowing for less repetition.

For example, let's say I often need to fetch models called Entity which are in a state of Not Deleted.  On my Entity model I have:

```
public static Func<Entity, bool> IsNotDeleted = e =>
    e.Versions != null ?
        e.Versions.OrderByDescending(v => v.VersionDate).FirstOrDefault() != null ?
            e.Versions.OrderByDescending(v => v.VersionDate).First().ActivityType != VersionActivityType.Delete :
            false :
       false;
```

(This is one of the smaller examples, mostly just checking for valid data before trying to examine that data.)

And using it would look like:

```
var entities = EntityRepository.Entities.Where(Entity.IsNotDeleted).Where(...
```

I'm finding, however, that while sometimes I want records which are not deleted, other times I want records which *are* deleted.  To do that, is there a way to invert the logic from the consuming code?  Something conceptually akin to this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
var entities = EntityRepository.Entities.Where(!Entity.IsDeleted).Where(...
```

I'd prefer not to have two `Func<>`s on the object, one for `IsDeleted` and one for `IsNotDeleted` which are nearly identical.  The `Func<>` returns a `bool`, is there a syntax to call the inverse of it when putting it in a `.Where()` clause?

Comment: Are you aware, that having that variable declared as `Func<T, TResult>` makes the query run as LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to Entities? You shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Marcin: Ah, I hadn't even noticed that.  We're working with such small data sets thus far that materializing them hasn't made a difference.  But it certainly *will* at some point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider the following extension methods.

```
public static class Functional
{
    public static Func<T, bool> Not<T>(this Func<T, bool> f)
    {
        return x => !f(x);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> f)
    {
        // 1. Break the lambda f apart into its parameters and body.
        // 2. Wrap the body expression with a unary not expression (!).
        // 3. Construct a new lambda with the modified body.
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Not(f.Body), f.Parameters);
    }
}
```

`Entity.IsDeleted.Not()` is the same as `Entity.IsNotDeleted()`.

Note you probably want to be using `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` - not `Func<T, bool>` - so that your lambda logic can be used database-side rather than client-side.

You can use it like this:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> isNegative = x => x < 0;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> isNonNegative = isNegative.Not();
```

Comment: Perfect, that should do the trick nicely.  And get me in more of the right way of thinking for the rest of these expression trees.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need full blown functional lambda decalration. Go the Church-Turing way - reccursion for the IsNotDeleted definition:

```
public static Func<Entity, bool> IsNotDeleted = e => !IsDeleted(e);
```

Answer above is even more "Church-Turing-y" :)